# How to use for loop to convert the values into dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, output

I am using several functions and i am using them to print values but now I need further calculation. So, I need to convert the printing values in a special format.

This is how my code looks:

```
for color in dominant_colors.colors:
        

        print('\tred: {0}'.format(color.color.red))
        print('\tgreen: {0}'.format(color.color.green))
        print('\tblue: {0}'.format(color.color.blue))
        print('')
```

and its printing values like this:

```
    red: 232.0
    green: 179.0
    blue: 124.0


    red: 160.0
    green: 152.0
    blue: 150.0


    red: 85.0
    green: 82.0
    blue: 81.0
```

But now I want the values in RGB format and that should be like this: `(232, 179, 124)`

So then I would like to get the column as dataframe which will give output like this:

```
Colors

(232,179,124)
(160,152,150)
(85,82,81)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension for list of tuples:

```
L = [(color.color.red, color.color.green, color.color.blue) for color in dominant_colors.colors]
```

Or loop solution with `append`:

```
L = []
for color in dominant_colors.colors:
    L.append((color.color.red, color.color.green, color.color.blue))
```

And then pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Colors':L})
```

Comment: Thank a lot. you are always best